# JWT authentication audience vs. issuer conflict?

Tags: authentication, jwt

Having a hard time figuring out what to use for audience and issuer in my jwt supported project. .NET Core ~6 Web API.

This is identical in the Startup for both:

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
            (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        
};
});
```

When my audience and issuer are identical to each other and in both apps, everything works. No token, no access. Supply the token, you get access.

Good configs identical in config file for both token generator and resource api project:

```
 "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "https://art1/",
    "Audience": "https://art1/",
    "Key": "This is a sample secret key"
  }
```

---

When I use this for token generator:

```
 "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "https://art1/",
    "Audience": "https://art2/",
    "Key": "This is a sample secret key"
  },
```

and this for resource api

```
 "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "https://art1/",
    "Audience": "https://art2/",
    "Key": "This is a sample secret key"
  },
```

It says it doesn't like audience "https://art2/". Now is that the audience specified in the token api or the audience specified in the resource api beign referred to?

What are the rules for how issuer/audience of token generator have to correspond to those configs setup in the resource api?

---

So I've run some experiments. It looks like so long as those JWT configs, audience, issuer, and key match between token app and resource app, things work fine.

Things were working on my local and failing in the dev environment because of case sensitivity.